# How do create a link from a database in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, slug

If you have a blog model in Django that saves a slug, how do you create an href link from that slug field?

Comment: in template: `<a href="/something/{{post.slug}}/">{{post.title}}</a>` 
in urls.py:   `url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/', views.something, name='post'),`

Answer (score 0):

You should create a view according to [Django MVT architecture](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/faq/general/#django-appears-to-be-a-mvc-framework-but-you-call-the-controller-the-view-and-the-view-the-template-how-come-you-don-t-use-the-standard-names).

For example you can create a [DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) and associate it with an URL.

```
# views.py

from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from someapp.models import SomeModel

class SomeModelDetailView(DetailView):

    model = SomeModel

# urls.py

from django.conf.urls import url

from someapp.views import SomeModelDetailView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', SomeModelDetailView.as_view(), name='somemodel-detail'),
]
```

And just use the [`{% url %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#url) template tag to access to this page. For example :

```
<a href="{% url 'somemodel-detail' foo.slug %}">{{ foo.name }}</a>
```

Where `foo` is a `SomeModel` instance.